# Programatically determine if settings is per User or per Application

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings, settings

Given an arbitrary settings parameter EG `Properties.Settings.Default.ArbitraryParam` can you tell programatically from within the application if this is a per User or per Application setting?

Alternatively, given that the per Application settings are read only, what is the best practice for protecting against attempts to write to a per Application setting?  Or will nothing happen aside from the value not being updated when `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` is called?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: @xxbbcc Why do you think it is confusing?  `properties.settings.default.xxxx` is a well known part of C# projects.  All I can do to clarify is to write a tutorial about what this is.

Comment: Well, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Aa730869%28v=VS.80%29.aspx, calling `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` saves user settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to determine if they are user scoped or application scoped, you can write a little extension method...

```
public static class SettingsExtensions
{
    public bool IsUserScoped(this Settings settings, string variableName)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = settings.GetType().GetProperty(variableName, BindingFlags.Instance);

        return pi.GetCustomAttribute<System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute>() != null;
    }
}
```

Which is then called:

```
Settings.Default.IsUserScoped("SomeVariableName");
```

You can do some more tricks if you want to get the actual name from a property, but it shows one way. The other way is to determine if the property contains both a `get` and `set` accessor (user scoped) or just a `get` (application scoped).

This is pretty clear if you open the Settings.Designer.cs file, here is my example file:

```
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "12.0.0.0")]
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("blah")]
    public string UserSetting {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["UserSetting"]));
        }
        set {
            this["UserSetting"] = value;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("hardy har har")]
    public string AppSetting {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["AppSetting"]));
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the attributes? They can be used to determine information about the properties.

However, another good way to tell is that if you write

```
Settings.Default.SomeAppSetting = some_value;
```

You will get a compiler error since there is no set accessor.

Comment: I just had a d'oh moment when I saw your comment about being no set accessor.  I had been thinking in terms of a wrapper to abstract the settings functionality (in order to make things more portable by hiding the implementation) and the lack of a set accessor means that I can't programatically deal with User vs Application settings and will have to deal with them manually on a case by case basis.